# What is the difference between "transaction-intensive" applications and "throughput-intensive" applications when using EBS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In Amazon EBS documentation, it [mentions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-io-characteristics.html) that :

> Transaction-intensive applications are sensitive to increased I/O latency and are well-suited for SSD-backed volumes. You can maintain high IOPS while keeping latency down by maintaining a low queue length and a high number of IOPS available to the volume. Consistently driving more IOPS to a volume than it has available can cause increased I/O latency.

> Throughput-intensive applications are less sensitive to increased I/O latency, and are well-suited for HDD-backed volumes. You can maintain high throughput to HDD-backed volumes by maintaining a high queue length when performing large, sequential I/O.

What are the differences between "transaction-intensive applications" & "throughput-intensive" applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throughput-intensive applications are applications that need to read/write *large* amounts of data. Think log ingestion, data warehousing or big data purposes. HDD-backed volumes like `st1` & `sc1` are recommended for these applications as the dominant performance attribute is the **throughput** (the *amount* of data going through) & will provide the lowest storage cost in most cases.

HDD-backed volumes only deliver optimal performance for **large, sequential** & most of the time, **infrequently accessed** I/O operations.

On the other hand, transaction-intensive applications are [applications where the dominant performance attribute is IOPS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volume-types.html). Think mission-critical, low-latency applications like databases, that are sensitive to storage performance and consistency. In particular, IOPS SSD volumes like `io1` & `io2` use a *consistent* IOPS rate, which you specify when you create the volume - this means you can get a sustained IOPS performance which you can't with any other EBS volume type.

SSD-backed volumes only deliver optimal performance for **small, frequent** I/O operations.

---

I assume you are asking this question to decide on the storage type for your EBS volume - essentially, **always use `gp3` *unless***:

- you need very high consistent IOPS for random I/O, in which case you should be using provisioned IOPS volume types like `io1` & `io2`
- you need to store lots of data & IOPS is not important in which case use `sc1` as a cold (storage) HDD
- you need to store lots of data & need frequent access in which case you should use `st1` as a throughput optimized HDD